# How are indexes effected when storing a date as text rather than integer in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQLite states that data can be represented as either Unix timestamps or dates.  Text is much more readable but integers takes up less row data and index data.

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

```
CREATE TABLE testDate (a DATETIME);
INSERT INTO testDate VALUES('1999-12-31 15:00:00');
INSERT INTO testDate VALUES(946652400); -- We will store one format or the other (not both)

SELECT typeof ( a ) FROM testDate;
'text'
'integer'
```

Our queries will be like

```
SELECT * FROM testDate 
WHERE a > '1990-12-31 15:00:00'
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM testDate 
WHERE a > 926652400
```

Will the index on a text date still work and will there be any *significant* performance loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes on text values work.

There might be a measurable performance difference, but whether this difference is noticeable, and whether this difference is significant four your particular application, depends on how much data you have, how fast your storage is, and how many queries you run.
You will have to measure this yourself.